# Find User from the params we get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a not a rails expert but i want to know that how can I find the User by its email as I'm getting before in params . & in else section I want to create new user by using that parameters

```
  def google
    user = User.find_by email: user[:email]
    if user
      user.generate_new_authetication_token
      json_response "User Information & already exist" , true, {user: user}, :ok
    else
          ??????????
    end
    if user.save
      json_response "Signed up Successfully ", true, {user: user}, :ok
    else
      json_response "something wrong ", false, {}, :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

And another private function from which I'm getting user params

```
private

 def google_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:uid , :email )
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_or_initialize_by` method. [reference](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by)

This is for you your case

```
def google
    user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: user[:email])
    if user.persisted?
      user.generate_new_authetication_token
      json_response "User Information & already exist" , true, {user: user}, :ok
    else
        #  ??????????
    end
    if user.save
      json_response "Signed up Successfully ", true, {user: user}, :ok
    else
      json_response "something wrong ", false, {}, :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I hope it should work.

Comment: i got this error here "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>",

Comment: actually i just want to sure if my user is present against this email or not if yes then I want to show message otherwise I ill add some extra attributes values and then save this

Comment: Please change `user[:email]` to `google_params[:email]`.